# A 0-measure uncountable superset of a countable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset [0,1]$ be countable. Is there a set $B\subset [0,1]$ such that $A\subset B$ and $B$ is uncountable with Lebesgue measure $0$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about $B=C\cup A$, where $C$ is the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)?

Recall that:

- $C$ is uncountable
- Lebesgue measure of $C$ is 0.
- Lebesgue measure of $A$ is 0, since it is countable.

Comment: Martin, thank you very much. The quote "A stitch in time saves nine" resonates in me as "Asking questions on Math.SE saves time."